GNOME control panel on the top right of the desktop doesn't follow the dark theme
I recently decided to install some themes on my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop. I liked how Orchis looks, so I went for it.
I thought everything was fine but then I realized the Dark Style switch in the control panel doesn't control itself and remains white even when it's turned on.
I tried changing the shell to orchis dark compact and it did make the control panel dark, but this time the power off menu stays white when the rest of the menu is dark.
I was wondering if this is a common issue with Orchis or if I did something wrong while installing the themes
Control panel is still white even though dark mode is selected everywhere.

